# Form Label to Indicate Childrens Prices Group And Those That Are Free of Cost

Tags: phrase-meaning, questions

Our company finds it difficult to word the notice indicating that infants under certain ages are either "free" or go at "half-price".

What should we use? "Free child age?" or ...? we're not native english talker so it make it lot harder...

thank you

I'm not sure what tags should be used. I will leave it up to the moderator to decide if more should be added.

---

### Previous Answer:

First i asked this question on another forum "english.stackexchange.com", and they told me that i should ask it here, i also share our Q&A up to now:

> This would be better asked on the EL Learners site. But "Under 10s -
>   half price; Under 5s - free" sounds alright to me. – WS2

---

> @WS2 first does stack have another section for english? second, it's
>   like key value field, which ask the user to enter the age which system
>   should consider to be free or half price... like: Q: A , Question
>   always is on the left hand side and the Answer is on the right hand
>   side – deadManN

---

> Anyway, I would go with something like "Maximum age for half price". –
>   Mr Lister 4 mins ago

---

> it'a a little long but i'm wonder if there is a better answer, also
>   it's harder for the child with no cost, also note that we should note
>   it to user that we meant infant or child or adult( as we saw many of
>   them, who don't get a thing after explaining things to them... Let me
>   move my Question – deadManN

Comment: I think the Title question is too confusing. Did you mean, "What is the accepted method to state pricing for chidren of a certain age?

Comment: What does your company do? Provide a service of some kind? It's children under certain ages, not infants. Infants are babies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually companies here (USA) display "kids 3 and under FREE" or after the price they will put "(Ages 2+)" or whatever the age specification is.

[HERE](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/tickets/?rate=southern-california-residents-offer)  is one example of how Disneyland words it.

Comment: Saying "3 and under",  "4 to 7", "8 and over" is clearest as it avoids the *"Does "over 10" include 10 year olds?"* question which is inevitably asked in these situations.  It's best to avoid "logical" descriptions like "Maximum age for half price" as it will just confuse people, regardless of how logically perfect you think it is.

Comment: @MaxWilliams what should the label be? we meant to put a label on the form, and in front of it a single box that user fill with number(which in this case is the allowed age to use this discount

Comment: @deadManN You could say "Age 3 and under - Free", "Ages 4-9 - £3", "Age 10 and above - £5" or something like that.

Comment: @MaxWilliams you naturally don't put label after text box, all the label data are on the left hand side of the box, BTW thanks

Comment: @deadManN This is a question about english, not web design.  I don't care how you lay it out, I was just suggesting some wording.

Answer (score 0):

You might use 'free entry age' or 'half-price entry age'. You definitely want to avoid the phrase 'free child' - that sounds like you're giving away free children, and would definitely get a laugh from some of your guests.